# What's the noun-form of "not working"?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

The phrase "not working" can be used as an adjective, for example:

> My laptop is not working.

What is the noun-form of the adjective "not working"?

E.g. "The not-workingness of my laptop."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could put a few options

"Brokenness" would be my first choice

"Dysfunctionality" would also work

"Failure" could work depending on the context too.

Comment: I would actually go for "Disfunctionality", but it isn't a word...

Comment: well, it is. I just spelled it wrong. I edited in the post.

Comment: With the Y we have "dysfunctional" which is a word.

Comment: @GEdgar - it's a word, but it's not the right word for this context.  **Dys-** means "with difficulty", not "not".  Anyway, I'd go for **bustedness**.

Answer (score 5):

***Inoperability*** could be added to the list of candidates.

Granted, in medicine, *inoperable* describes being *unsuitable for surgury without undue risk* (as in, an *inoperable* tumor).

However, *inoperability* has another meaning; which Collins describes as *the state of being unworkable, or incapable of being operated*. TFD lists it as the noun form of *inoperable*, which means *not functioning* or *inoperative*.

Answer (score 4):

I like J.R.'s ***Inoperability.*** I might also suggest:

- incapacitation
- nonfunctionality
- paralysis

Answer (score 3):

Malfunction could be used, but it may suggest a compromise of functionality that is less than total.